# How do I downgrade the gradle wrapper version in my Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to downgrade the gradle wrapper version in my Android Studio project. First I tried:[image]

But I kept getting this error after changing the version to 2.13:

[image]

Then I tried here:

[image]

I tried cleaning the project. I tried deleting the build folder and rebuilding/Syncing, none of these things worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make sure that in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle: the setting "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" was selected instead of "Use local gradle distribution"

[image]

Comment: @Giszmo I added another detail to the answer that may fix it.